# MySQL: JOIN query on 3 tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am currently learning MySQL and want to write a simple dictionary application.
Currently I have 3 tables:
Language1:
ID | Word

Language2:
ID | Word

Dict:
ID_Lang1 | ID_Lang2

Now I am struggling to make a query that looks in both language tables for the word and via the dict table finds the corresponding word in the other language.

What I was trying was like:
select lang1.ID, lang2.ID from Language1, Language2 WHERE lang1.word OR lang2.word = 'Random'
and to join this somehow together with the Dict table, but could not make it work.
Hope someone will enlighten me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM `dict` d
    LEFT JOIN `language1` l1 ON d.`id_lang1` = l1.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `language2` l2 ON d.`id_lang2` = l2.`id`
WHERE
    l1.`word` LIKE 'random'
    OR l2.`word` LIKE 'random'
```

Comment: Hi! Works fine aswell, but it queries for too many variables for my case. But thanks anyway! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Performance of query will get hit as Dict becomes larger, but this is just one way to do it:

```
SELECT L1.ID, L2.ID
FROM Language1 AS L1
     INNER JOIN Dict AS D ON D.ID_Lang1 = L1.ID
     INNER JOIN Language2 AS L2 ON D.ID_Lang2 = L2.ID
WHERE L1.Word = 'Random'
      OR L2.Word = 'Random'
```

Comment: Hi By changing L1.ID and L2.ID to L1.word and L2.word it works perfect for me! Thanks a lot!